# How to resolve development branch dependencies

Tags: git

I have a development branch ("A") complete but not yet merged into the master. I have started working on another branch ("B") to implement another feature and find that the new branch depends on A (the second feature cannot be implemented without A). So, what to do? (I don't want to merge A into the master branch yet).

Comment: No doubt this is a duplicate. I have searched and researched and cannot find an answer.

Comment: Merge A into B?

Comment: rebase or merge A into B.

Comment: Consider merging A into master and then rebase B onto that merge. Or merge A into B.

Comment: So, how do I merge A into B? (All the examples I can find assume you are merging into master. I can assume merging A into B is pretty similar, but I don't want to break something.)  Yes, I am very much a beginner in git and am working on my own on a website with 80,000 users. Not ideal, but that's life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fair simple. We are currently following same practice.

- Master On 01/Jan
- Release 1 branch taken from master on 05/jan
- Release 2 branch taken from master on 25/Jan

We know release 2 will go after release 1. Anyhow while doing release 2 we will have changes in master and so on release 2.  What we do is merge branch Release 1 to release 2 frequently to get updates. This will prevent later head-ac of merging lot of changes and after merge surprises in release 2 branch.

Hope this adds value. Thanks. Please comment if any more info needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've done. I worked out for myself what i commands I needed to do this. It didn't go smoothly (things on git rarely do) - some extra pull was required in the middle of it - but it seems to have done what I required.